# SQL Server: how to find closest location?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geo

I have two tables, Houses and Stores. Both have Latitude and Longitude fields. I need to make a view that would return for each record in Houses HouseId and StoreId, where StoreId is the ID of the store closest to the house. I do have a function CalculateDistance(float Long1, float Lat1, float Long2, float Lat2). 
But I cannot come up with the query that would make the view I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Example From one of my Applications... You will need to remap the columns and tables obviously.

```
DECLARE @Lat float= -83.555
DECLARE @Long float = 43.555
SELECT TOP 100 ID, Abbr, Distance FROM 
(
    SELECT NL.NodeLocationID AS ID, NL.NodeLocationAbbr AS Abbr, (ABS(NL.Latitude - @Lat) + ABS(NL.Longitude - @Long)) / 2 AS Distance 
    FROM NodeLocations AS NL
    WHERE (NL.Latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (NL.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
) AS D1 
ORDER BY Distance
```

The below finds the closest items relative to other items in the same table (can be altered by changing NL2 to another table). This works to find the closest items, however performance is horrid depending on how many records your dealing with. I would suggest you create a static field and calculate each one via a background process.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
        , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Distance ASC) AS Rnk
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT NL.NodeLocationID AS ID, NL.NodeLocationAbbr AS Abbr
                , NL2.NodeLocationID AS ID2, NL2.NodeLocationAbbr AS Abbr2
                , (ABS(NL.Latitude - NL2.Latitude) + ABS(NL.Longitude - NL2.Longitude)) / 2 AS Distance 
            FROM NodeLocations AS NL
                JOIN NodeLocations AS NL2 ON NL.NodeLocationID<>NL2.NodeLocationID AND (ABS(NL.Latitude - NL2.Latitude) + ABS(NL.Longitude - NL2.Longitude)) / 2 <= 0.1
            WHERE (NL.Latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (NL.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
                AND (NL2.Latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (NL2.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
        ) AS D1 
    ) AS D2
WHERE D2.Rnk=1
```

Comment: Doesn't take into consideration the curvature of the Earth or the difference between Long and Lat and such, but works generally well on most populated placed on the planet.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me that this doesn't do what I need. It only returns distance from various locations to one given location. But I need something else.

Comment: I just modified to add another SQL. my original code was from a given existing point.

Comment: Thanks Darren. But you see, your query now finds locations that are very close to each other. But I need to find for each house the closest store, even if it is not actually close, i.e. the distance should be min(Distance).

Comment: Yeah I got you on that one. I don't have similar data to do the same idea and my data is huge I was operating on (which is why I added the restriction on distance. But that SQL returns the closest location to all other locations (I have only "Houses", in your terms). You should be able to replace the second "NodeLocations" with your "Stores" table, change the Join to a CROSS JOIN without any criteria and you will get the one closest Store to each location.
Is hard to deal with this kind of thing without access to the data :), hopefully the idea will help you

Comment: Thanks. I will try it on Jan 2nd.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working, though very slow. But I guess nothing can be done about it.

Comment: Do it in the background and store the result in the table in a new field. If you need the value to be updated in real time afterward you can add a trigger with the single query I posted first.

Comment: the distance measured as km or m?

Comment: @user998405 sorry units not considered in this case, it's just a relative distance of LAT and LONG considered as a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Geography` row (Geocode) in your table and populate it from your `Latitude` and `Longitude` :

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
   SET [Geocode] = geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude , 4326)
GO
```

And then query the closest location from coordinates:

```
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(-121.626 47.8315)';  
SELECT TOP(1) Geocode.STDistance(@g), ShopId FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Geocode.STDistance(@g);
```

It will return the closest from your coordiantes.